# Errors in CSS variables and calculations: How can I get error output?

Tags: css, error-handling, css-variables, css-calc

I started working with CSS variables to try out making a modular sizing scale. But I quickly ran into problems where CSS values were ignored but I did not see any indication on what was wrong.

Let's see a minimal reproduction of the problem:

```css
:root {
  --ratio: 1.25;
  --font-size-medium-heading: calc(var(--ratio) * 1rem);
  --font-size-large-heading: calc(var(--font-medium-heading) * var(--ratio)); /* note the typo in the var */
}

h1 {
  font-size: var(--font-size-large-heading);
}
```

I made a typo on purpose to see what will happen (I have left out `-size` from the variable name). Since my heading got mini I tried querying the value of my new CSS variable:

`getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--font-size-large-heading') === ''`

It returned an empty string.

Let's head to Chrome's style inspector and see if I get the warning sign ⚠️:
[image: font-size-large-heading shows up as a valid property, no warning sign]

MDN advises to use a CSS validator. So let's try out this: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator
[image: Well it really was not updated recently]

My guess is that this validator is not really up-to-date (if anyone using it still).

**Update**
I understood that according to the spec it is *a valid statement*, but the computed-time value of it is invalid. I want to know about these as it is just hiding the true problem in a very frequent mistake (if you have ever spent a day on finding out that Angular expected a `"'thing'"` instead of `"thing"` in a template, you will understand how bad is having no output about invalid values).

**Is there a way to get an error output about computed-time invalid CSS `var`s and `calc` values?**

Comment: nothing is broken in your code an everything is valid. You are using a var called `--font-medium-heading` and it's valid even if you didn't define it. You will have an invalid value only at computed time OR maybe you will define it later in your code

Comment: @TemaniAfif see my comment below to Zohir Salak's answer; I don't mind if it is valid, I mind that I can't find anything telling me that a value was ignored. That's a billion dollar mistake.

Comment: *but the computed-time value of it is invalid.* --> you have no computed value because you are not using the variables yet

Answer (score 0):

**First the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/#using-variables)**

> If a property contains one or more `var()` functions, and those functions are syntactically valid, the entire property’s grammar must be assumed to be valid at parse time. It is only syntax-checked at computed-value time, after var() functions have been substituted.

This why you don't see the yellow triangle in chrome devtool, because syntax wise it's valid.

---

From the [spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/#substitute-a-var) focus on the fourth rule

> 4. Otherwise, the property containing the var() function is **invalid at computed-value time**

Also

> A declaration can be **invalid at computed-value time** if it contains a **var()** that references a custom property with the **guaranteed-invalid value**

The third line in your code contains a **var()** that references a css variable with the **guaranteed-invalid value**

---

**Why?**

> The initial value of a custom property is a [**guaranteed-invalid value**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/#guaranteed-invalid-value). As defined in [§ 3 Using Cascading Variables: the var() notation](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/#using-variables), using var() to substitute a custom property with this as its value makes the property referencing it invalid at computed-value time.

A none-existing css variables basically creates it and it's initial value is the guaranteed-invalid value.

---

**What's that initial value compute to ?**

> This value serializes as the empty string, but actually writing an empty value into a custom property, like `--foo: ;`, is a valid (empty) value, not the guaranteed-invalid value. If, for whatever reason, one wants to manually reset a variable to the guaranteed-invalid value, using the keyword initial will do this.

This is why `getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--font-size-large-heading')` returns an "empty string" **(guaranteed-invalid value)**

Comment: That's great, but still does not solves the issue: _I want to get notified about these_. If there is no way for identifying these unintentional `guaranteed-invalid value`s then it is a language design mistake; similar to `try { /* ... things... */} catch { /* empty */ }`, it will waste millions of hours.

Comment: @atoth it's not a language design mistake but CSS. Don't think about it like C++. CSS variables doesn't work like other variables. You can only know the invalid computation (and I say only) when using the variables with a property. With the code you gave you have no way to know if it's invalid (unless you implement you own algorithm). The only way to identify this is to use the variable inside a property, read the computed value of that property and then check. Also note that *computed-value time* is **only** triggered when a property is in play and not when a variable is using another one.

Comment: @TemaniAfif by reading the computed property do you mean using it on an element? Say `p { font-size: var(--invalid-var); }`? Because in that case we get the empty string issue, so it will be `p { font-size: ; }`

Comment: @atoth no you won't have empty string but you will fallback to another value. From the Spec: *When this happens, the computed value of the property is either the property’s inherited value or its initial value depending on whether the property is inherited or not* -- so in your example ( `p{font-size:var(--invalid-var):}`) you will not have any empty string but it's like you did nothing and the default font-size will apply to p.

Comment: @atoth check this: https://jsfiddle.net/ugvnewy0/ ... you think your variable inside root is invalid and logically the h1 using it will be erroneous but no. I have defined the same variable again and for one h1 it applied so it's fine and if I remove the first h1: https://jsfiddle.net/ugvnewy0/1/ then nothing is wrong and the variable inside root is not used so nothing is invalid in this case. You should not think at variable level but only (and only) at property level because the variable make no sense until it's used. What do you think about this: https://jsfiddle.net/ugvnewy0/2/ invalid?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Sorry for the late reply. I have checked your examples. I do not agree with this statement `it's like you did nothing`. In your first example `<h1>` is much smaller than the default size; so that I consider already erroneous. My second problem with it is that this is still not good enough for me: I need to find a way to get **notified** about these "empty" or "ignored" values apart from UI glitches. How can I get that?

Comment: @atoth How do you expect to get notified ? like through the browser complaining in the devtool ? or a script ?

Comment: @ZohirSalak If possible through a browser devtool, through an error console, anything. If there is a script then it can be made into an extension/plugin, so that might work as well.